# ASP.NET Ajax retry callback after timed out

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, callback

I have a page that contains a treeview control in an update panel. When user expand a node on treeview, it causes an ajax callback to the server. Server adds new rows to the expanded node and returns to the client. But sometimes, connection problems may arise. I'm handling errors for this. When a connection error occured, I want to show a "Retry" button for retry last ajax action. My question is: How can I retry last ajax action from Microsoft Ajax Library (Javascript)?

PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the endRequest event of the pipeline.

Here is my example how you could solve your problem. Scriptmanager is required. I also used jquery but that is optional:

I have a button that is doing a long operation. Such a long operation in fact that it's causing a timeout

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLongOperation" runat="server" OnClick="btnLongOperation_OnClick" Text="Click for magic..." />

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upStuff" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLongOperation" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On the server side this method is called. HttpTimeout is raised after 90 seconds. Because the threads sleeps for 100 seconds it will always end in a timeout.

```
protected void btnLongOperation_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
}
```

Now I added this piece of javascript to subscribe to the endRequest event. If this event is raised I can check if the result of the request is an error and if the error is type of TimeoutException. If so I can act accordingly.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //subscribe to endRequest
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        });

        function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            //only act if sender is my button
            if (sender && sender._activeElement && sender._activeElement.id === "btnLongOperation") {
                //only act if response is an error type of Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException
                if (args && args.get_error() && args.get_error().name && args.get_error().name.indexOf("TimeoutException") >= 0) {
                    alert("retry could be handled from here");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

It's a quick and dirty solution but should solve your problem. You might want to refactor the javascript code a little to make it less smell ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much :). But, how can I retry "exactly" last request on alert()'s line? I tried to save Sys.Net.WebRequest object by handling beginRequest event (I got it by args.get_request()). Then tried to call that reqest's .invoke() method in endRequestHandler. But it generated a Sys.InvalidOperationException (messsage: invoke has been called more than one time.). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The easiest way would be `sender._activeElement.click();` But when you click on an image in your treeview to expand a node the img will be the activeElement. In this case you have to use `sender._activeElement.parentNode.click();`

Comment: Ok. I understood that simulating user's last action is the easiest way to do that, as you say. Thanks again...